# Proof of Runge's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, complete-spaces

Reference-Functions of one complex variable by John B.Conway(Graduate text in Mathematics)[image]

The proof starts with some  important introductory information-[image]

I've  already  shown that $ C(K,\mathbb C)$ is a complete metric space,but i'm not getting how to show **$\rho (f_n,f)\rightarrow $ iff $f=u-lim f_n$**

Now the main proof begins-The proof comprises of 3 lemmas-

[image]

[image]

[image]

- I got stuck in the very first lemmma(1.8).Please tell me how to show if $f,g\in B(E)$ then $f+g\in B(E)$?
- What is in the square block in lemma(1.9)?

**PROOF OF LEMMA-1.8**
Since,$f_n\implies f$ & $g_n\implies g$($\implies$ represents uniform convergence),so for given $\epsilon >0$ we can find $N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb N$ such that $\vert f_n(z)-f(z)\vert<\frac{\epsilon}{2}    \forall z\in K$ whenever $n\geq N(\epsilon)/2$.

Similarly, for given $\epsilon >0$ we can find $M(\epsilon)\in\mathbb N$ such that $\vert g_n(z)-g(z)\vert<\frac{\epsilon}{2}  \forall z\in K$ whenever $n\geq M(\epsilon)/2$.

Now consider,$\vert (f_n+g_n)(z)-(f+g)(z) \vert \leq \vert f_n(z)-f(z)\vert +\vert g_n(z)-g(z)\vert <\epsilon /2 +\epsilon/2 =\epsilon \forall z\in K$ and$ n\geq L(\epsilon):=\max{M,N}$.

so,$f+g\in B(E)$

Is it correct?How to show that $f+g$  has poles in $E$?

**PROOF OF LEMMA 1.9**
[image]

How does $\partial G \subset \partial V$ happen??

Comment: Do you know what $u$ is? Because I don't.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos :I also did't get how $"u"$ came into picture.

Comment: @PKStyles I don't have the book, but I think maybe Conway uses the notation $u-\lim$ to denote uniform convergence? Can you check if he introduces this notation somewhere?

Comment: @MarcPaul:here is pdf http://math.unice.fr/~nivoche/pdf/Conway1.pdf ,you seems correct,check on page 29

Comment: @MarcPaul:see the edit

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos:See the edit

Comment: What is $C(K,\mathbb{C})$? continuous complex functions defined on $K$?

Comment: if  whole $V \subset U $then how can $\partial V \cap U=\phi$?this is in reference to lemma 1.9.Can  some one please give an example satisfying this condition?

Comment: square block means emptyset.

Comment: @C.Ding:yes,you get it correct

Comment: It does happen when $V=U$ is an open ball.

Comment: @C.Ding:If $V=U$,then $V$  cannot be properly contained in $U$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68275/discussion-between-c-ding-and-pk-styles).

Comment: How does $\partial G \subset \partial V$ happen??

Comment: See the edit in my answer.

Comment: @C.Ding:also see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510306/proof-of-runges-theorem-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$f+g\in B(E)$:**

You have proved  that if $f_n\Rightarrow f$ and $g_n\Rightarrow g$ on $K$ then $f_n+g_n\Rightarrow f+g$ on $K$. And it will be better if you state that the pole of $f_n+g_n$ lies in poles of $f_n$ and $g_n$.

There is no need to prove that $f+g$ has a pole in $E$ since $f+g$ is defined on $K$.

**$\partial G\subset \partial V$:**

**Lemma 1.** Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $A$ is a component of $X$, then $A$ is closed in $X$.

**Lemma 2.** Suppose $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $A$ is a component of $X$, then $A$ open.

Back to your question, $G$ is open by lemma 2. Let $E=V\backslash G$, then $E$ is open in $V$ by lemma 1 and thus $E$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$.

\begin{align*}
\partial V & =\overline{V^c}\cap \overline{V}\\
& =\overline{(G\cup E)^c}\cap \overline{G\cup E}\\
& =(G^c\cap E^c)\cap (\overline{G}\cup\overline{E})\\
& =(G^c\cap E^c\cap \overline{G} )\cup (G^c\cap E^c\cap \overline{E})\\
& =(G^c\cap \overline{G})\cup (E^c\cap \overline{E})\\
& =\partial G\cup \partial E.
\end{align*}
 The penultimate equation is because $\overline{G}\subset E^c$ and $\overline{E}\subset G^c$.

So the following conclusion is obatained:

> **Conclusion.** Suppose $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $A$ is a component of $X$, then $\partial X=\partial A\cup\partial (X\backslash A)$.

Comment: :how can you write  $\overline{(G\cup E)^c}=(G^c\cap E^c)$?

Comment: :Also for $A$ to be open in $\mathbb C$ ,$A$ can be written as $\mathbb C \cap $(open set in $\mathbb C$).What open set can i choose?

Comment: @PKStyles Note that $(G\cup E)^c=G^c\cap E^c$ is closed.

Comment: I guess that you are talking about lemma2, and that you mean for $A$ to be open in $X$,   $A$ can be written as $X\cap $(open set in $\mathbb{C}$). In fact I mean $A$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$ in lemma 2, but I think there is no need to clear that since $A$ is open in $X$ is equivalent to $A$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$ whenever $X$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$.