# Proof of Runge's theorem 1

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Extension of [Proof of Runge's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507329/proof-of-runges-theorem/2507475?noredirect=1#comment5183676_2507475)

[image]

[image]

> - **Since $Q_n(z)$ is a rational function with poles in $E$ then $Q_n(z)   \in B(E)$.Also,since $a\in V\subset \mathbb C$
>     so,$(z-a)^{-1}Q_n(z)\in B(E)$ as $B(E)$ is algebra.Is this reasoning
>     correct?**
> - **How $V$ is open?**

Comment: Is this Conway?

Comment: @Teddy38:yeah!!!!

Comment: **1.** I think  you are right.  **2.** 1.11 implies for any $a\in K$ the open ball $B(a, d(a, K))\subset V.$