# Problem in proof of Runge's theorem-

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

Extension of [Proof of Runge's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507329/proof-of-runges-theorem/2507475?noredirect=1#comment5183676_2507475)

[image]

- **How does the condition on $b$ in equation $11.1$ guarantees the  existence of number $r$,$0<r<1$ such that $\vert b-a \vert \ <r\vert  
   z-a\vert \forall z\in K$?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $r\in\left(\frac{|b-a|}{d(a,K)},1\right)$. Then $r<1$ and, if $z\in K$,$$|b-a|<r.d(a,K)\leqslant r.d(a,z)=r.|z-a|.$$

Comment: :also see this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510306/proof-of-runges-theorem-1