# Suppose $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$ and $B$ is a component of $X$ then $B$ is open in $\mathbb C$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

*Suppose $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb C$ and $B$ is a component of $X$ then $B$ is open in $\mathbb C$.*

To show this it is enought to show that

> $B$=(some open subset of $\mathbb C$)$\cap \mathbb C$.

**What is that "some open subset of $\mathbb C?$"**

Comment: did you mean $B = (\dots)\cap X$ in there?

Comment: What definition of "component of $X$" are you using?
The point behind "some open subset of $\mathbb{C}$" is that it is a hint that rather than directly studying $B$, it might be easier to show that it is the intersection of some obviously open subset and $X$ (The "$\cap \mathbb{C}$" is almost certainly a typo). Since both that chosen open set and $X$ are open, so is their intersection.

Comment: @Chessanator:THe source of this question is lemma 2 in  the answer by C.Ding https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507329/proof-of-runges-theorem?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @NickPavlov:In a nutshell,my question is how can we show that $B$ is open in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @C.Ding:How can we show that $B$ is open in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: what I would do is use the concept of local connectedness - are you familiar with that? Two of the basic properties of locally connected spaces are that their components are open subsets of them, and that an open subset of a locally connected space is itself locally connected

Answer (score 0):

For any $x\in B\subset X$, there is an open ball $U$ in $X$ containing $x$ as $X$ is open. 
Since every open ball in $\mathbb{C}$ is connected and  $U\cap B\neq \emptyset $, $U\cup B\subset X$ is connected. 
Because  $B$ is a component of $X$ which is a maximal connected subset of $X$, $U\subset B$. 
Therefore $B$ is open.

For a more general case, you can follow  Nick Pavlov's comment. Note that an open subsapce of $\mathbb{C}$ is locally connected.